# Strange behavior when modifying a class variable in function and return value

Tags: java, android

Given the following

```
public class MyClass {
    private String my_string = "bbb";

    public MyClass() {
        this.my_string += testFunc();
        System.out.print("my_string = " + this.my_string);
    }

    public String testFunc() {
        this.my_string += "aaa";
        return "ccc";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass my_class = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
my_string = bbbccc
```

Expected:

```
my_string = bbbaaaccc
```

So what's going on here?  What happened to the line `this.my_string += "aaa";`?

Comment: the line is not ignored

Comment: Why so many down votes and no explanations as to why?

Answer (score 3):

```
this.my_string += testFunc();
```

Is the same as

```
this.my_string = this.my_string + testFunc();
```

So:

```
this.my_string = "bbb" + testFunc();
```

`testFunc()` might change this.my_string, but that doesn't matter, because it returns `ccc`. So it turns to:

```
this.my_string = "bbb" + "ccc";
```

`this.my_string` will now be changed to `bbbccc`, so it doesn't matter that you previously changed it to `bbbaaa`. The output is right.

Comment: If memory serves right, functions are evaluated before operators, however it would seem that `+=` is evaluated to `= this.my_string +` before the function `testFunc()` is evaluated.  Would you happen to be able to provide some reference on this?

Comment: The translation of `a += b` to `a = a + b` is not an evaluation though. Technically, there's also a typecast hidden in that translation, but that's kind of besides the point right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple java thing, when you call `my_string += testFunc()` you can no longer change the value of `my_string` in your method.. Java does not pass the reference of objects to method like `C` so side effects get applied in an order and `my_string += testFunc()` override changes made by `this.my_string += "aaa"`.

For desired effect you must change your code to this:

```
String temp = testFunc();
my_string += temp ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error but a conceptual JVM decision.

As you're calling the method inside the constructor, that means the objects was not created yet so JVM does not allow internal properties changes on it.

You're trying modifying something that does not exist (speaking of object oriented concepr rahter than procedural

Comment: Not sure, because if you try to do `this.my_string = testFunc() + this.my_string`, the output will be `cccbbbaaa`. So the modification done in testFunc inside the constructor was not ignored. Here, it's just that this.my_string was evaluated before modification( as @Mark said) and not because it does not yet exist.

Comment: Yes the used value is outdated regard to testFunc() change when is used inside constructor. That makes people thinking it is ignored but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
private String my_string = "bbb"; //my_string = bbb

public MyClass() {
    this.my_string += testFunc(); //my_string + returned string of testFunc()
    System.out.print("my_string = " + this.my_string);
}

public String testFunc() {
    this.my_string += "aaa"; // writing temporaly into my_string
    return "ccc"; ( // overwrite aaa with ccc
//my suggestion -> return this.my_string (+ or += dunno which one.. eating :D)"ccc"; instead of return "ccc";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass my_class = new MyClass();
}
```

}